# should i use foundation in actual project development

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation, customization

i heard foundation is excellent in rapid prototyping like bootstrap? I do not know the difference of bootstrap and foundation yet. I want to dive in to foundation but i need to know if we can use it not limited to prototyping, let say developing actual project?

Comment: Using bootstrap is easy but i find hard customizing bootstrap even using its less file and mixins. Is customizing foundation based in our needs is easier or just same as bootstrap?

Comment: Customizing bootstrap or foundation is going to be same more or less. You can check out my website clickmynotes.com. It is built using foundation and I had customized a thing or two. Feel free to use the CSS/JS from the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly can use Foundation in production projects, but there are best practices, such as using custom classes by extending/mixing in modules with SASS. The advantage to this is you can [write your HTML semantically, and turn off modules you're not using, and avoid a bloated compiled CSS by turning off a few variables.](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/734-trying-to-understand-include-html-classes)

I found Foundation to be advantageous because it was more design agnostic than Bootstrap. That said, with any framework, there reaches a point where bending a framework to meet your needs is more work than starting from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now i'm gonna dive into foundation and sass.